# Deterministic address calculation?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ether, addresses

proxy contract

```
contract ERC20ProxyDelegator {
    constructor(ERC20Votes _token, address _delegate) {
        _token.approve(msg.sender, type(uint256).max);
        _token.delegate(_delegate);
    }
}
```

Main contract function which creates the proxy contract.

```
    function retrieveProxyContractAddress(
        ERC20Votes _token,
        address _delegate
    ) private view returns (address) {
        bytes memory bytecode = abi.encodePacked(
            type(ERC20ProxyDelegator).creationCode, 
            abi.encode(_token, _delegate)
        );
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                bytes1(0xff),
                address(this),
                uint256(0), // salt
                keccak256(bytecode)
            )
        );
        return address(uint160(uint256(hash)));
    }
}
```

In the above contract creation code I have seen that the salt is not unique.If i can managed to give the same inputs all the time (_token ,_delegate) can i able to produce same address all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, given none of the inputs change, this function is deterministic. However, if any of the inputs (salt, creationCode, _token, _delegate) change, this will change. It should also be noted that this function is deterministic at each address it is deployed to, but would return different addresses for the same salt, creationCode, _token, and _delegate combination if it were called on two different instances (contract deployments).